# Group of covering tansformations of universal covering for Riemannian manifold is total discontinuous?

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, riemannian-geometry

Picture below is from Do Carmo's Riemannian Geometry. I use the [definition of covering map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covering_space). In this definition, if assuming $V_i\cap V_j =\emptyset ~(i\ne j)$ ($V_i$ is sheet), then I know how to get the red line, namely the $\Gamma$ is total discontinuous. But in Wiki or Munkres' Topology, the covering map don't need $V_i\cap V_j =\emptyset ~(i\ne j)$ (although, I feel it is right). So, I don't know how to get the red line.

> [image]

Comment: The disjointness of the sheets is part of the definition of the covering. In the Wikipedia page you link to, this is hidden in the "disjoint union" sign $\sqcup$ that is used.

Comment: @AndreasCap  Thanks, I thought $\sqcup$ just be $\cup$.